# django InlineAdmin: Fill Field Value after a Select-Change (ForeignKey)

Tags: django, django-admin

**Models and Admin Classes**

```
class ListItem(models.Model):
        quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
        isKleinmenge = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        product = select2.fields.ForeignKey(ProductVariant, blank=True, null=True, overlay="Produkt...")
        sortOrder = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, blank=False, null=False)

        invoicePrice = models.FloatField(default=0)
        invoiceText = models.TextField(default="", blank=True, null=True)
```

I use that Model as an Inline on my Invoice.

```
class ProductsInline(SortableInlineAdminMixin, admin.TabularInline):
        model = ListItem
```

On my Invoice

```
class InvoiceAdmin(DjangoObjectActions, admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ ProductsInline, ]
```

**Question**
Inside djangoAdmin: When a Product is selected via Dropdown (in ListItem Inline Element), i want to copy Text/Values from selected Product into "invoiceText" and "invoicePrice".

Idea is that the End-User can then correct the invoiceText and invoicePrice if he wants/has to.

How can i do that?
How can i detect the change in the Select Form and react to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution can be using `jquery`.

```
add jquery to product admin :

class InvoiceAdmin(DjangoObjectActions, admin.ModelAdmin):
inlines = [ ProductsInline, ]
class Media:
    js = (
        '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js', # jquery
        'my_script.js'
    )
```

and in `my_script.js` :

```
$("select#product").change(function() {
    // do what ever you want
});
```

Comment: I've done the exact same thing multiple times in my admin. Thumbs up for simple solutions using the Media class.

Comment: Perfect and clean solution! Thanks!

Comment: i dont understand why this only partially works for me, jquery and my_script.js are loaded, but the `$("select#product").change(function()` does not work.. also tried to use `$("select#id_product").change()` according to django-admin generated fields but this also does not work. using `console.log()` i discovered that any js code before and after it does run well..

Comment: even found another similar solution, but there i have the same issue: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html

Answer (score 1):

additionally to hasan's correct answer:
i actually (python3-django 2.2.3) had the problem that my jquery part didnt run because the document was not completely loaded. i found out, django loads my_script.js before the document finished loading and could not work because select element was loaded afterwards. so checking first for `$(document).ready()` works:

```
$(document).ready(function(jQuery) {
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('select#id_product').on('change', function() {
            alert('product selection changed.');
        });
    });
});
```